# JdbcTemplate query, what is it?

Tags: java, sql, spring

In our project I came across the following method:

```
public void saveDailyPlayersAccount(Date date) {
  JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  template.queryForRowSet("SELECT public.saveDailyPlayerAccount(?);", new Object[]{date});
}
```

The issue was caused by the query-string `"SELECT public.saveDailyPlayerAccount(?);"`, passed to the `queryForRowSet` doesn't look like an `sql`-query. What does that actually mean?

Comment: You could take a look at this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a call to a stored procedure. Where the ? gets substituted with `date` (it is a `Object[]` actually).

Comment: Actually, the questionmark gets substituted by `date`, which is contained in an `Object[]`.